# Visual Studio 2015 debugging annoying boxes

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015

I'm developing a universal windows app in vs 2015 (C#)

When I run the application, two little black boxes with white numbers are always blocking my way (I can't see my app behind), these boxes are located in the top-left and the top-right of the window
[image]

Please tell me what are these boxesand how to get rid of them??

thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have never seen or used these counters, but a quick Google search shows that they are Visual Studio Frame Rate Counters that are used for debugging purposes.

Apparently you can disable them with the following code in your app.   I have no tested this so I make no guarantees to whether it works or not.

Here is a good article that describes this functionality though and shows the exact boxes you are describing:

http://www.kunal-chowdhury.com/2015/12/uwp-frame-rate-counter.html#fqDguKy73ZwohOYh.97

```
#if DEBUG
    if (System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached)
    {
        this.DebugSettings.EnableFrameRateCounter = false;
    }
#endif
```

Hope this helps.